# How to bind up arrow in ~/.inputrc (readline) for vim insert mode?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, readline

When in Readline apps with vim mode enabled in ~/.inputrc (`set editing-mode vi`) is there a way to bind the `<Up>` arrow key in `vi-insert` mode? To display previous history item, for example. It seems I have to press ESC key first, only then it works.

Here's my attempt at making it work (~/.inputrc):

```
$if mode=vi
  # INSERT MODE
  set keymap vi-insert
  "\e[A": history-search-backward # up-arrow
  "\e[B": history-search-forward  # down-arrow
```

Also note, that when I press `Ctrl+v` and then `<Up>`, it prints `^[[A`.

I did manage to have it working like I want in zsh:
http://paulgoscicki.com/archives/2012/09/zsh-vi-mode-with-emacs-keybindings/

Answer (score 0):

What you want works in `bash` already: I can use up-arrow to display the previous history item in vi-insert mode. The following command shows how it is configured. Perhaps you are confusing `history-search-backward` with `history-prev`?

```
$ bind -m vi-insert -p | grep hist
# beginning-of-history (not bound)
# dynamic-complete-history (not bound)
# end-of-history (not bound)
"\C-s": forward-search-history
# history-and-alias-expand-line (not bound)
# history-expand-line (not bound)
#  (not bound)
# history-search-forward (not bound)
"\eOB": next-history
"\e[B": next-history
# non-incremental-forward-search-history (not bound)
# non-incremental-forward-search-history-again (not bound)
# non-incremental-reverse-search-history (not bound)
# non-incremental-reverse-search-history-again (not bound)
"\eOA": previous-history
"\e[A": previous-history
"\C-r": reverse-search-history
# vi-fetch-history (not bound)
```

Comment: You're confusing **READLINE** with shell. I have no problems configuring the desired behaviour in my shell of choice, which is zsh. I have problems with Readline apps, like Postgresql console, IRB, etc.